# Angular Dart tutorial section 4 - 'Future not resolved'

Tags: angular, dart, future

Total newbie to Dart and Angular. Long-time SW developer with a lot of experience with multiple languages and platforms.

I'm working through the 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial, but am stumped in [section 4.](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt4), under the heading 'The Hero Service returns a Future'.

Thus far, I've gotten things to work pretty well, but now when I try to mod the code to return a future (per the tutorial), I get an error.

In hero_service.dart, this:

```
Future<List<Hero>> getHeroes() async => mockHeroes;
```

and in app_component.dart, this:

```
  Future<Null> getHeroes() async {
     heroes = await _heroService.getHeroes();
     }
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: 'package:Tour_Of_Heroes/app_component.dart': malformed type: line 
            86 pos 3: cannot resolve class 'Future' from 'AppComponent'
            Future<Null> getHeroes() async {
            ^
```

I've backed it out and re-entered everything to make sure I've entered everything correctly and still getting the error.

I'm wondering if something in the core was refactored and I need to import something else or clean the build (not sure how to do that...) to get it fresh or what.

(BTW: Doing everything from the CL and VIM.  Webstorm was a disaster...)

Comment: What code is at line 86? I think you need to post more code. Have you tried checking with DartAnalyzer? Why was WebStorm a disaster. I'm using is since 1.5 years and it's usually working great.

Comment: Have you remembered to add `import 'dart:async';` ? (The library that `Future` is in.)

Comment: import 'dart:async'; -- Bingo!  I figured it was something like that. I didn't see it in the tutorial -- it may have been factored out of core since the tutorial was written.  'importing' it in both files did the trick. I'm still learning the packages...

Comment: The biggest hassle with WebStorm is it doesn't seem to trigger builds on save -- I can't tell when the server is running and when it isn't (this is on OS X Sierra).  And, all of these IDE's try to do too much -- code dances around as I type, windows constantly pop up all the time as I type -- if I type a quote it adds the second one and then positions the cursor _after_ the second quote (not helpful).  And, I can't figure out how to bring up the pub console -- it comes and goes on its own.

I imaging I could figure out settings and all, but that's another road block.

Comment: Anyway, better to understand how all the different pieces work in the beginning, I think, and that means CL.

Comment: Sublime Text wit the Dart module works quite well, although there appears to be no ongoing development on that module so it will eventually break. I'm also trying out Atom and its Dart support.

Comment: Running dartanalyzer over your source would immediately show you such errors.

Comment: @rickb - sorry about the troubles you had. I've created an issue so that this gets fixed: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-webdev/issues/585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to add `import 'dart:async';` ? (The library that `Future` is in.)